# std::sort in vector<int> returns 0 instead of the values

Tags: c++

Im doing a simple exercise in HackerRank, get some ints in a vector and print them sorted in the screen.

```
int main() {
    int sz;
    std::cin >> sz; // 5 in this case

    std::vector<int> v(sz);
    for(auto elem : v){
        std::cin >> elem;
        std::cout << elem << ' '; //1 6 10 8 4
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto elem : v) {
        std::cout << elem << ' '; //0 0 0 0 0 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1 6 10 8 4 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Is there something else to take in account with the std::sort? Is it a problem with HackerRank's compiler?

Answer (score 5):

`elem` is a **copy** of the items in your vector! Change it to be a reference so you'll actually be modifying the vector when reading in values:

```
for(auto &elem : v){
//      ^^^
    std::cin >> elem;
    std::cout << elem << ' '; //1 6 10 8 4
}
```

See it work here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/uUb8V2)

Comment: Yes it was that, thanks!